# How to add logo in mvc layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in _Layout.cshtml

```
   <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
```

instead of "your logo here" I want to add the logo image.

Comment: `Html.ActionLink` will only generate text. You will need to manually construct your html (making use of `Url.Action`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that you have to make some changes like below.

```
<p class="site-title">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
        <img src="your/img/path.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

For MVC layout page, you can implement it, in this below mentioned way:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                <img src="~/Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Site Logo" style="height:25px; width: 25px" /></a>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application Name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
</div>
```

You can style it, the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default to your image:
Default:

```
<div class="float-left">
    <p class="site-title"><a runat="server" href="~/">your logo here</a></p>
</div>
```

Copy your image (e.g. “your_image.png” into the already-created “Images” directory and add the “img” tag with that filename as listed below.  The example below also changes the “href” to point to your URL (www.your_url.com/) which obviously you would change to whatever Website you need:

```
<div class="float-left">
    <p class="site-title"><a runat="server" href="http://www.your_url.com/"><img src="../Images/ your_image.png" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
```